# Use PhoneGap to Check if GPS is enabled

Tags: cordova, mobile

I am building an app using PhoneGap. While using the Geolocation API of phonegap I realized that the APIs time out for two reasons and the same error is thrown:
1. If GPS is not enabled on the user's device
2. If GPS is enabled and is not able to get the location of the user (could be several reason, faulty GPS, unclear weather and so on)

I am having an issue in differentiating the cause? Any thoughts on how to do it?

I was wondering if there is any way, I can check if GPS is active on user's device using Phonegap, so that i can do that as a separate check and direct user to the settings window where typically GEO settings are placed. Not sure how to do that? a custom phonegap plugin may be?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could check the error code in [PositionError](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#PositionError) parameter of [geolocationError](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocationError) in your call to [getCurrentPosition](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition).  I am guessing that it will be PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED when gps is not enabled, and PositionError.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE or PositionError.TIMEOUT when gps is enabled but there are other issues.

Note that this is platform dependent.  You would probably have to write a contrived error message that says "Could not get the current position.  Either GPS signals are weak or GPS has been switched off".

One thing you can try is to call getCurrentPosition with an incredibly small timeout, say 1 ms.  If it says permission denied, you can conclude that gps is disabled and if it times out, you can assume that gps is enabled.  I do not have time to test this, you could probably edit this answer with result of your tests.

Another thing you can try is to use the [diagnostic phonegap plugin for android](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic).  You will have to make sure you use the plugins for the other platforms also, but they are all also mostly there.

Comment: Thanks Kinjal, different error code will definitely solve the problem, but the issue here is i am getting the same error code- PositionError.TIMEOUT in both cases, i.e. when GPS is not enabled and when GPS returns is not able my location. BTW, I am testing it on HTC phone running Android 2.3, I am yet to test it on other devices

Comment: A short heads up on this. Depending on device and OS version, the error callback will **not fire**. For example on my Galaxy S2 I _immediately_ get an error when GPS is disabled. On the other hand every S3 and S4 I've tested so far never fired the error callback (only after timeout), even though GPS is completely disabled. The PhoneGap team is aware of it though.

Comment: @Prinzhorn your comment is very useful.  Would you mind specifying exactly the error (i.e. error message) you get when GPS is disabled on the Galaxy S2.  For the S3 and S4 it seems a really short timeout solves your problem, correct?

Comment: @StevenWexler sorry, I haven't used PhoneGap in three months and don't plan to do so in the next months

Answer (score 6):

To handle this case most gracefully, you can use [`cordova.plugins.diagnostic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic) to check if GPS setting is enabled and (on Android 6+) check if app has run-time authorization, and (if it's not enabled), use [`cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) to automatically switch on GPS via a native dialog without requiring users to manually switch it on via the settings page. However, since the latter relies on an up-to-date Google Play Services library on the device, it is good practice to fallback to the manual switching if the automatic switching fails.

[image: Example app demo]

First add the required plugins to your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic --save
cordova plugin cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy --save
```

Then you'd do it something like this:

```
function checkAvailability(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationAvailable(function(available){
        console.log("GPS location is " + (available ? "available" : "not available"));
        if(!available){
           checkAuthorization();
        }else{
            console.log("GPS location is ready to use");
        }
    }, function(error){
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
    });
}

function checkAuthorization(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAuthorized(function(authorized){
        console.log("Location is " + (authorized ? "authorized" : "unauthorized"));
        if(authorized){
            checkDeviceSetting();
        }else{
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
                switch(status){
                    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED:
                        console.log("Permission granted");
                        checkDeviceSetting();
                        break;
                    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED:
                        console.log("Permission denied");
                        // User denied permission
                        break;
                    case cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.DENIED_ALWAYS:
                        console.log("Permission permanently denied");
                        // User denied permission permanently
                        break;
                }
            }, function(error){
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    }, function(error){
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
    });
}

function checkDeviceSetting(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationEnabled(function(enabled){
        console.log("GPS location setting is " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
        if(!enabled){
            cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(function (success){
                console.log("Successfully requested high accuracy location mode: "+success.message);
            }, function onRequestFailure(error){
                console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
                if(error.code !== cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
                    if(confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
                        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                    }
                }
            }, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }
    }, function(error){
        console.error("The following error occurred: "+error);
    });
}

checkAvailability(); // start the check
```

Comment: But where does 'cordova' comes from on the code? It seems that it is only threw out in the code. Is there any dependency injection I should use?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with some devices. Managed to resolve it with the code below:

```
var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried DaveAlden's solution above but it didn't work, partially because the first function he calls `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isGpsLocationAvailable()` is Android-only per the [plugin docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic).

As he says, first add the two plugins:

```
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic --save
cordova plugin cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy --save
```

Then add the following functions:

```
// Checks to see if GPS is enabled AND if the app is authorized
checkEnabled(){
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationAvailable(
      (available) => { onSuccess(available); },
      (error) => { goToSettings(error); }
    );
}

onSuccess(available) {
  if(available) { // do something };
  else goToSettings(available);
}

// Output error to console
// Prompt user to enable GPS, on OK switch to phone settings
goToSettings(error) {
  console.log("error: ", error);
  if(window.confirm("You need to enable location settings to use the geolocation feature.")) {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToSettings();
  }
}

checkEnabled(); // Run check
```

Hope this helps someone else who comes along this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using apache cordova 3 android platform

In the GeoBroker.java file on the exectute method add the following action after the locationManager has been instantiated.

```
if(action.equals("isGPSEnabled")){
            PluginResult result;
            if ( locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )){
                result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
            }else{
                result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
            }
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
        }
```

Then in the geolocation.js file in the plugins folder of your assets add the expose the new functionality

```
 /**
     * Asynchronously checks if gps is enabled.
     *
     * @param {Function} successCallback    The function to call when gps is enabled.
     * @param {Function} errorCallback      The function to call when gps is not enabled. (OPTIONAL)
     */
    isGPSEnabled:function(successCallback, errorCallback){
        exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Geolocation", "isGPSEnabled", []);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i cant find this file ... or i have to create this file if yes where to create it ?

Comment: @quicklearner note that the solution is for version 3 of apache cordova. Maybe it was renamed in your version. Anyway you should find a java file under the folder of the plugin that uses PluginResult and a js file inside the www folder

Comment: well i appreciate your concern but i would like to know which plug in are you talking about ? have not installed any

Answer (score 0):

Just for new users redirected here there is a plugin (which started about the middle of 2014) which is called [Cordova diagnostic plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#isgpslocationavailable):

> This Cordova/Phonegap plugin for iOS, Android and Windows 10 Mobile is
>   used to manage device settings such as Location, Bluetooth and WiFi.
>   It enables management of run-time permissions, device hardware and
>   core OS features. [`ref`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#overview)

Comment: But where does 'cordova' comes from on the code? It seems that it is only threw out in the code. Is there any dependency injection I should use?

Comment: @luizfzs What do you mean by injection? When you add some plugins to your Cordova app it will be added as a global variable or under another global one (which is mostly Cordova itself).

Comment: It's weird because I've installed cordova-diagnostic but whenever I compile, I get the "Cannot find name 'cordova'" message.

Comment: I believe you made a mistake somewhere else. You should check your code again using *chrome inspector* _chrome://inspect/device#devices_