# Get coordinates from Hardware GPS

Tags: javascript, php, android, geolocation, gps

I've found a lot of questions about GPS Coordinates but not one that confirms using the mobile hardware GPS instead of Web GPS like geoLocation and such like.

**My actual method:**

I'm using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`, the `Lat/Long` comes from the Web, here's the code:

```js
function getGPS(funcCallBack)
{
   if (navigator.geolocation)
   {
     var timeoutVal = getCookie("GPSTimeout");
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(sucess
                                             ,error
                                             ,{enableHighAccuracy: true
                                              ,timeout: timeoutVal
                                              ,maximumAge: 0}
                                             );
   }
   else{
   alert('GPS is turned off, or was not possible to find it. Now, doing the login without localization.');
   window.gpsLat = 0;
   window.gpsLng = 0;
   window.gpsAcc = 0;
   funcCallBack();
   }
   function sucess(position) //sucess
   {
      window.gpsLat = position.coords.latitude;
      window.gpsLng = position.coords.longitude;
      window.gpsAcc = position.coords.accuracy;
      funcCallBack();
    }
    function error()         //error
    {
      window.gpsLat   = 0;
      window.gpsLng   = 0;
      window.gpsAcc   = 0;
      funcCallBack();
    }
}
```

**My problem:**

Sometimes when I do the login I am not getting the GPS Coordinates (they come 0) and sometimes I am getting coordinates with more than 2,000 Accuracy (that is not precise).

By the way, I am testing the GPS on a data internet service, when I do use a Wi-Fi connection it works perfectly with less than 100 Accuracy.

**Details:**

Maybe you are complaining about:

1. `timeoutVal`: it is a cookie with the number `5000` inside it.
2. `funcCallBack`: it is a function that continues the login operation.
3. `window.gpsLat`: it is a global var containing the `Latitude` value got from the `geoLocation`.
4. `window.gpsLng`: it is a global var containing the `Longitude` value got from the `geoLocation`.
5. `window.gpsAcc`: it is a global var containing the `Accuracy` value got from the `geoLocation`.

**What do I want?**

I want a solution in JavaScript or PHP that can get coordinates from the mobile hardware device, the Native GPS, not the geolocation, and when the Native GPS is turned off, ask the user to turn it on.

Comment: sometimes the first couple readings are spotty while the GPS "warms up" to the satellite array above your particular location. you can also check the frequency of returns on watchPosition() to detect gps/wifi: wifi doesn't update very often, but gps is a tiny bit noisy.

Comment: As eddiec suggested in the last lines of his answer, if you're building a mobile application, you should _definitely_ use a framework like PhoneGap, which offers in most times full or semi-full access to native GPS implementation. Using build-in browsers solutions is a weak idea. BTW: Don't be confused -- PhoneGap API's has the same function names for Geolocation object, like Geolocation in browsers (HTML5), but empowers much more adequate native GPS implementation behind it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should get the location with javascript not PHP. PHP is only capable of doing an IP lookup which is the least accurate method for determining location.

The way `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` works is it uses the most accurate data currently available. In the case of a mobile device it will use GPS first if enabled, then wi-fi.

If native GPS is enabled javascript will access that data instead of the wi-fi data, but there is no way of preventing a check against the wi-fi data if the GPS data isn't available.

Your best solution is to check the accuracy field and if it's not within a range you're happy with ask the user to enable GPS.

Alternatively if you're building a hybrid app, most of the frameworks (PhoneGap .etc.) have APIs to query the device GPS directly. [Use PhoneGap to Check if GPS is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006454/use-phonegap-to-check-if-gps-is-enabled)

Comment: are you sure that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` uses the most accurate data currently available? And too, do you know the average `Accuracy` of the native gps?

Comment: And too, i faced some problems with browsers, like when i use firefox browser i can get the GPS coordinates from data internet service and when using opera or any other browser i only can get 0 coordinates, do you know what is that?

Comment: It does give the most accurate (so native GPS if available), but I can't tell you the average I'm sure it depends on the device and conditions. Really you don't care where the data comes from as long as it's within an accuracy threshold.

Comment: Additionally you can run JS in an android device now with the latest version of chrome, that will be able to give you some test data to start from.

Comment: +1 for the useful info about `geoLocation` and the hint about `PhoneGap`, maybe i can suggest for my boss to start using it, but at the moment he only wants a webpage that anyone can easily access just by typing a URL in the browser, do not needing to download anything or install anything to the `Phone`.

Answer (score 4):

Geolocation API does not expose a direct way to check whether GPS is on or off, but you can catch the errors of geolocation and base on error type can draw conclusions from there.

E.g. POSITION_UNAVAILABLE (2)   if the network is down or the positioning satellites can’t be contacted. 
But its not sure short way you have to handle some conditions!

I will suggest use watchPostion { i agree its meant to watch and continuous to locate position} u can keep it on and if GPS throw the error u can prompt custom alert to make user turn on the GPS device/wifi/internet .. and if its come to success callback u can clear the watch.

```
 var watch =null;
 function success(position)
{
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lon= position.coords.longitude;
   if (watch != null ) 
 /*Need to take care .. as maybe there is no gps and user 
  want it off so keep attempt 3 times or some kind a way out otherwise it will 
  infinite loop */
    {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watch);
        watch = null;
    }

}
function getLatLon()
{
    var geolocOK = ("geolocation" in navigator);
    if ( geolocOK ) 
    {
        var option = {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge: 0,timeout:10000 };
        watch =  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, fails,  option);
    }
    else {
        //disable the current location?  
    }
}
function fails()
{
    alert("please turn on the GPS !");
}
getLatLon();
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, its a nice answer, but i do not want to watch the Position, i only want to get it one time to send it to my server and save on the database to know where the user was when he logged in. Too, as far i am using data internet service(that is a poor slow service here) i need to use less internet as possible to do that.

Comment: I can think only solution :-) that do above js on first hit and keep lat/lon at server or cookie side than turn it off/donot include in next hits this geolocation js.