# GPS status in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I am new in Phonegap. I want show user location via network or GPS. I want to know GPS status, like GPS now is off or enable or disable? And if GPS is off, the app go to settings for on GPS, if GPS is disable, GPS be on. I don't know, Can i find this with phonegap or should write a plugin for this? I mean, i should write a plugin for android and another plugin for IOS?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006454/use-phonegap-to-check-if-gps-is-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for Android [here](https://github.com/BastienL/GPSDetector) and another [here](https://github.com/oaugustus/phonegap-diagnostic-plugin)

on iOS, the error callback will tell you the location services are disabled if that is the reason it was not able to locate.