# How can i enable GPS in cordova app

Tags: cordova, gps, location

i add plugin to GPS enable use cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy but error occur to build the Android app.

i add in my config.xml file add to build  but it is not working how can i get the version of cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy please suggest me.

Comment: can U post which error u r getting ??

Comment: can u pls tell me the latest version of this plugin 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" source="npm" />
i add this in my config.xml file

Comment: 2.2.0 is the latest version

Comment: thanx 4 your suggation but i get the same error to build the app.
Error - The minSdkVersion as specified in your config.xml (or the default value of 14) is less than required by a library included in your application: com.google.android.gms.location - You can fix this.

Comment: i add this in my congig.xml file
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="2.2.0" />

Comment: can u catch me on my mail.id: naresh.k.suruvu@gmail.com

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13006454/2401386) helps you.